# urlgrabber with gzip support

Tags: python

What's the recommended way to handle `Content-Encoding: gzip` files when using [urlgrabber](http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/)?

Right now I'm monkey-patching it like this:

```
g = URLGrabber(http_headers=(("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"),))
g.is_compressed = False # I don't know yet if the server will send me compressed data

# Backup current method of handling downloaded headers
try:
    PyCurlFileObject.orig_hdr_retrieve
except AttributeError:
    PyCurlFileObject.orig_hdr_retrieve = PyCurlFileObject._hdr_retrieve

def hdr_retrieve(instance, buf):
    r = PyCurlFileObject.orig_hdr_retrieve(instance, buf)
    if "content-encoding" in buf.lower() and "zip" in buf.lower():
        g.is_compressed = True
    return r
PyCurlFileObject._hdr_retrieve = hdr_retrieve

g.urlgrab(url, dest)

if g.is_compressed:
    # ungzip file here
```

But it doesn't look very clean and I fear it's not threadsafe either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a threadsafe solution:

```
g = URLGrabber((http_headers=(("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"),)))
g.opts._set_attributes(grabber=g)
try:
    PyCurlFileObject.orig_setopts
except AttributeError:
    PyCurlFileObject.orig_setopts = PyCurlFileObject._set_opts

    def setopts(instance, opts={}):
        PyCurlFileObject.orig_setopts(instance, opts)
        grabber = instance.opts.grabber
        grabber.is_compressed = False

        def hdr_retrieve(buf):
            r = PyCurlFileObject._hdr_retrieve(instance, buf)
            if "content-encoding" in buf.lower() and "zip" in buf.lower():
                grabber.is_compressed = True
            return r

        instance.curl_obj.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, hdr_retrieve)
    PyCurlFileObject._set_opts = setopts
```

but it still doesn't feel quite "clean" :)